# working with multiple <video> tags using videojs() function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, video.js

I am trying to run videos on multiple video tags using videojs but woth no results. I am getting the error `TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)` I am initiating different `id` properties for each `<video>` tag based on the id's that they have received through a REST based call.

Should I be having an array of videoplayers instead of one as suggested by other links? Here is my source code:

video.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('controller.video', [])
        .controller('Video', ['$scope', 'model', '$sce', function ($scope, model, $sce) {

            $scope.ids = [];
            $scope.videos = {};
            $scope.titles = {};
            $scope.specialtyvideos = null;
            $scope.likes = {};
            $scope.comments = {};

            $scope.getVideos = function () {
                model.get('specialty', 'Colorectal').then(function (res) {
                    $scope.specialtyvideos = res.data;
                    for (var i=0 ; i<$scope.specialtyvideos.length ; i++) {
                        $scope.videos[$scope.specialtyvideos[i]._id] = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.specialtyvideos[i].src);
                        $scope.titles[$scope.specialtyvideos[i]._id] = $scope.specialtyvideos[i].title;
                        $scope.ids.push($scope.specialtyvideos[i]._id);
                    }
                });
            };

            $scope.specialtiesVideo = function (id) 
            {
                var element = ""+id;
                console.log(id);
                console.log(videojs);
                var vjs = videojs(id);
                vjs.aspectRatio("16:9");
                vjs.autoplay(false);
                vjs.controls(true);
            };

            $scope.getLikes = function (id) {
                model.get('likes', id).then(function (res) {
                    $scope.likes[id] = res.data.length;
                });
            };

            $scope.getComments = function (id) {
                model.get('comments', id).then(function (res) {
                    $scope.comments[id] = res.data.length;
                });
            };

            $scope.initialize = function () {
                $scope.getVideos();
            };

        }]);
})();
```

html file (view using angularjs):

```
<ion-view id="page17" class=" " ng-controller="Video" ng-init="initialize();">
      <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="list card" ng-repeat="i in ids">
          <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="">
            <h2>{{ titles[i] }}</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="container" ng-init="specialtiesVideo(i)">
              <div class="videocontainer">
                  <video class="video-js" id="{{ i }}" src="{{ videos[i] }}"></video>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
              <i class="icon ion-thumbsup" ng-init="getLikes(i);"></i>
              {{ likes[i] }} Likes
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
              <i class="icon ion-chatbox" ng-init="getComments(i);"></i>
              {{ comments[i] }} Comments
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
              <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
              Share
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

here are the dependencies in the main index html page:

```
<link href="lib/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- OTHER REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES-->

<script src="lib/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "/lib/video.js/dist/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

[image: this is a stacktrace of the error occuring. I am pretty sure that I put in a string as a parameter]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem when I realized that my angularjs code was executing much faster than the rendering of the webpage. I used a dynamic array of videojs for each of the many videos that I had to play in a single page. (Though I think a single videojs instance would do).

All I had to do next was to delay the particular function using the `$timeout` which is a wrapper for `window.setTimeout` by angularjs.

Here is the code snippet that solve the error:

```
           $scope.specialtiesVideo = function (id) 
        {
            var element = id;
            console.log(id);
            var confirm = document.getElementById(id);
            console.log(document.getElementById(id));
            $scope.videoplayers[id] = videojs(id);
            console.log("videojs enabled for the video identified by ID :"+id);
            $scope.videoplayers[id].aspectRatio("16:9");
            $scope.videoplayers[id].autoplay(false);
            $scope.videoplayers[id].controls(true);
        };

           $timeout(function() {
            for (var id=0;id < $scope.ids.length;id++) {
                $scope.specialtiesVideo($scope.ids[id]);
            }
           }, 20000);
```

where 20000 is the number of milliseconds I gave as a window for the page to render and the stack to clear after executions after which I executed the function shown in the code above.